# How to compare array values with one to many relations in laravel

Tags: mysql, for-loop, eloquent, laravel-8, relationship

I have an input array of submaterials. $submaterials = [1, 2,3]

I am using lumen framework connected with mysql. I have a one to many relation with material and submaterial table. That's a material can have many submaterials.

Here my requirement is to get materials which have same submaterials in input. I only need to get materials which have exact same number of submaterials and same submaterials in input array

This is the query i have added

```
$submaterials_array = [12,13];
$otherrequests = for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($submaterials_array); $i++) 
{
    $id = $submaterials_array[$i];
    Offerrequest::whereHas('submaterialprops', function ($q) use ($id) {
        $q->where('submaterial_id', $id);
  });
}
$otherrequests = $otherrequests->get();
```

I have tried the query and I got a list of all offerrequests with submaterial id='12,13'. But I want to get only rows which have exact these submaterials(one to many relation). That means it should not return rows with submaterial 12,13,14 or 12,13,14,15,16.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a material model and your one to many relationship defined on the material model is called submaterials and that $submaterials is the array of ids. You could try using https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

There may be other ways to do this but you could dynamically build the query by looping through the submaterials and adding a whereHas for every submaterial.

```
$materialQuery = Material::has('submaterials', '=', count($submaterials));

foreach($submaterials as $submaterial){
    $materialQuery->whereHas('submaterials', function (Builder $query) use ($submaterial){
        $query->where('id',$submaterial);
    });
}   

$material = $materialQuery->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This code is somewhat right and will outputs all material which has either of submaterials. Becoz we used whereIn. If we use where instead of wherein then all materials will be listed which has input array of submaterials. However if submaterials array is [1, 2,3] and consider there is a material with submaterials 1,2,3,4. This also list in that result. But i only want to retrive the materials which have exactly the same number and same values of submaterials. Is there any solution to this result using eloquent?

Comment: So this doesn't filter out materials with submaterials greater than the amount listed?  `Material::has('submaterials', '=', count($submaterials))`

Comment: Thanks a lot. The code worked. Before it was a mistake

Comment: But here i am getting rows which has either of these submaterials. i need exact match of submaterial array in relation

Comment: I see, the reason whereIn didn't work is because that will allow any material with at least 1 matching submaterial (as long as it passes the count condition). I edited the solution so maybe that will work for you.